# Using MoveBase without Lidar or a SLAM Map

Tags: ros

I know, an unusual set up.

What I would like to do is to leverage the local path planning algorithms.

What I think I want to do is to use it to drive the robot from where it is to the target (the fiducial) - without regard to obstacles or maps.

Because I want the robot to arrive not just at the destination point but oriented correctly (that is aligned with) the target. That information is in the tf between the robot and the target.

At the bottom of it all I think is a relatively straightforward calculation of a spline but instead of reinventing that wheel I would like to see if I can actually use ROS code which will be better tested and more efficient.

I’ve been digging around various books, algorithms, sample code and the actual source code and I am getting oriented. But has anyone tried to do this (or done this) and can give me your thoughts?